# Reorder PySpark dataframe columns on specific sort logic

Tags: apache-spark, sorting, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, multiple-columns

I have a PySpark dataframe with the below column order. I need to order it as per the 'branch'. How do I do it? `df.select(sorted(df.columns))` doesn't seem to work the way I want.

**Existing column order:**

```
store_id,
store_name,
month_1_branch_A_profit,
month_1_branch_B_profit,
month_1_branch_C_profit,
month_1_branch_D_profit,
month_2_branch_A_profit,
month_2_branch_B_profit,
month_2_branch_C_profit,
month_2_branch_D_profit,
.
.
month_12_branch_A_profit,
month_12_branch_B_profit,
month_12_branch_C_profit,
month_12_branch_D_profit
```

**Desired column order:**

```
store_id,
store_name,
month_1_branch_A_profit,
month_2_branch_A_profit,
month_3_branch_A_profit,
month_4_branch_A_profit,
.
.
month_12_branch_A_profit,
month_1_branch_B_profit,
month_2_branch_B_profit,
month_3_branch_B_profit,
.
.
month_12_branch_B_profit,
..
```

Comment: `sorted()` will use string prefixes, so yes, all `month_1` values will "go together", for example

Comment: thanks for the edit. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manually build your list of columns.

```
col_fmt = 'month_{}_branch_{}_profit'
cols = ['store_id', 'store_name']
for branch in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
    for i in range(1, 13):
        cols.append(col_fmt.format(i, branch))
df.select(cols)
```

Alternatively, I'd recommend building a better dataframe that takes advantage of array + struct/map datatypes. E.g.

```
months - array (size 12)
  - branches: map<string, struct>
    - key: string  (branch name)
    - value: struct
      - profit: float
```

This way, arrays would already be "sorted". Map order doesn't really matter, and it makes SQL queries specific to certain months and branches easier to read (and probably faster with predicate pushdowns)

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use some python coding. In the following script I split the column names based on underscore `_` and then sorted according to elements `[3]` (branch name) and `[1]` (month value).

Input df:

```py
cols = ['store_id',
        'store_name',
        'month_1_branch_A_profit',
        'month_1_branch_B_profit',
        'month_1_branch_C_profit',
        'month_1_branch_D_profit',
        'month_2_branch_A_profit',
        'month_2_branch_B_profit',
        'month_2_branch_C_profit',
        'month_2_branch_D_profit',
        'month_12_branch_A_profit',
        'month_12_branch_B_profit',
        'month_12_branch_C_profit',
        'month_12_branch_D_profit']
df = spark.createDataFrame([], ','.join([f'{c} int' for c in cols]))
```

Script:

```py
branch_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c not in{'store_id', 'store_name'}]
d = {tuple(c.split('_')):c for c in branch_cols}
df = df.select(
    'store_id', 'store_name',
    *[d[c] for c in sorted(d, key=lambda x: f'{x[3]}_{int(x[1]):02}')]
)

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- store_id: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- store_name: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- month_1_branch_A_profit: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- month_2_branch_A_profit: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- month_12_branch_A_profit: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- month_1_branch_B_profit: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- month_2_branch_B_profit: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- month_12_branch_B_profit: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- month_1_branch_C_profit: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- month_2_branch_C_profit: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- month_12_branch_C_profit: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- month_1_branch_D_profit: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- month_2_branch_D_profit: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- month_12_branch_D_profit: integer (nullable = true)
```